# Error al momento de cerrar mi modal

Tags: php, javascript, html5, json, bootstrap

**Cuando ejecuto el botón me abre mi modal pero al momento de clickear afuera del modal se cierra y no puedo volver abrir el modal,dejare el codigo para que sea entendible, tengo la duda si podra ser como creo el JS?.**

**Este es mi boton Modificar**

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#scrollmodal" onclick="modificar_logotipo('.$rows["ID"].')" class="btn btn-default"> MODIFICAR</button>
```

**Este es mi JS**

```
function modificar_logotipo(ID) {

                var parametros = {
                    "id_logotipo": id_logotipo
                };
                $.ajax({
                    data: parametros,
                    url: 'logotipo/modificar_logotipo.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $("#todos").html('<section class="content"><div style="margin: 20% 0px 0px 0px;"  align="center"><img src="img/bgif.gif" width="150"><br>Procesando, espere por favor...</div></section>');
                    },
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#todos").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
```

**El formulario que abre el modal**

```
<div class="form-group">                    

                        <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" class="form-control" />
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_logotipo; ?>" id="id_logotipo" name="id_logotipo" class="form-control"/>
                            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $nombre_logotipo; ?>" id="nombre_logotipo" name="nombre_logotipo" class="form-control"/>

                </div>


                <div class="panel-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Limpiar</button>
                    <button type="button" id="botonSubidor" href="javascript:;" onclick="uploadAjax($('#nombre_logotipo').val(),$('#id_logotipo').val());return false;" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Modificar</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: ¿estás usando bootstrap?

Comment: si estoy usando bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

En bootstrap puedes configurar los modales via atributos, prueba a añadir al elemento `#scrollmodal` los atributos `data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static"`.

Aquí tienes el enlace a la documentación https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes

Comment: Gracias, me sirvió

Comment: De nada, un placer. Si te ha servido, puedes considerar marcar la respuesta como aceptada, pero eso lo dejo a tu criterio ;)